# Converting RTSP to HLS as close to realtime as possible

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, hls

What flags do I use to make ffmpeg convert RTSP into an HLS playlist with the video stream as close to realtime as possible?

We would rather have instantaneous video, without regard for bandwidth, quality, or stability.